# How to use a repeted map in .proto file

Tags: python, grpc

i want to use a repeted map in proto file in order to get a list of map with a python file

this is my code in proto file

```
message Nationality {
  map<string, string> names = 1;
}

message cv_response {
  peopleData people = 1;

  message peopleData {
    repeated Nationality nationalities = 1;
  }
}
```

The result i got

```
{
  "people": {
    "nationalities": [
      {
        "names": {
          "FR": "Français"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The desired result

```
{
  "people": {
    "nationalities": [
      {
         "FR": "Français"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```